# Is there a risk that genetically modified organisms displace genes of other species via horizontal gene transfer?

Tags: genetics, gene

It is known that species can rely on certain genes to survive. See for example [this publication](https://www.science.org/doi/pdf/10.1126/science.abf2232?casa_token=WGESkXZKDJIAAAAA:czYHwC4ezKKFhJIlpiwtNU2Ki6HNWsNN9oLa1uXiBocImtlmHb-LMqnlrPIeeqIamGkGRuNPeeCR5HPY).

An argument often made by environmental groups is that genes introduced by genetically modified organisms can spread via horizontal gene transfer and could potentially displace native genes and thus lead to extinction of organisms. Are there any publications which support that assertion?

Answer (score 4):

[converted from a comment that got unwieldy]

Why necessarily HGT and not simple breeding? There is a term [genetic pollution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_pollution) for this, looks like it's somewhat controversial as an environmental issue but it seems a more readily available means (and undoubtedly happens at some rate).

HGT of e.g. microbial antibiotic resistance is [well-founded](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8226744/), but there's not much evidence that lab antibiotic resistance genes are anywhere near as good as "natural" resistance genes. We tend to just use stuff that's already in nature.

One might look at [glyphosate resistance in weeds](https://www.ars.usda.gov/ARSUserFiles/64022000/publications/reddy/nandula-grw12.pdf), given the very high rate of glyphosate usage and glyphosate-resistant agricultural varieties. However that linked 2005 USDA report doesn't even bother to mention introgression from ag varieties, instead focusing on the much more numerous weeds that are naturally resistant, or have evolved resistance in response to glyphosate pressure in the field. [Here is a more recent pop science article](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/weeds-are-winning-the-war-against-herbicide-resistance1/) arguing that weed evolution is by far the most acute problem in this case.

So it's formally possible that genes escape from GMOs to the wild, but I'm not sure that there are any reports of genetic pollution actually being a "problem" from an environmental point of view (at least relative to the much more prevalent naturally occurring resistance).

There are of course still plenty of good reasons not to use glyphosate resistant varieties or antibiotics more broadly! There is [some evidence](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2152265021001518) of a glyphosate-cancer association, and more generally relying on these tools to support industrial monocultures has tons of environmental problems. Glyphosate application is almost certainly contributing to extinctions. It's more that this particular objection to biotechnology (GMOs escaping and outcompeting non-GMOs) isn't too convincing.

Answer (score 1):

Horizontal gene transfer is a poor argument against green gene-technology. Like most arguments, it boils down to "The method in general is totally fine, it's just Monsanto that's evil, since as a monopoly, they do/did whatever the f*** they want".

The problem of horizontal gene transfer would be solved by transforming not the nuclear genome, but ***chloroplasts*** ([Ruf et al.2021](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33905600/)). By doing so, plants that reproduce in the wild "dilute" the transgene with each subsequent generation. However, this technique isn't seen in the industry.

I know that my botanics professor mentioned chloroplast transformation in a one-hour rant about the unfairness/stupidity towards green gene-tech. He also stated that restrictive laws allowed Monsanto to become a monopoly, which freezed any progress in this kind of industry. RoundUp everywhere.

Chloroplast transformation seems really promising though ([Siddiqui et al 2020](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31538673/)).